# VM 9.0 with windows server 2008 data center hangs when restarting it

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machine

I have installed VM workstation 9 on my windows 7 64x, my environment specification are as follow:

1. windows 7 professional 64x
2. 32 GB RAM
3. 670 GB hard disk
4. VM workstation 9
5. create  a new VM and I mount and ISO image of windows server 2008 data center (I gave the VM 16 GB RAM).

the problem I am facing is as follow:-

1. I have installed the windows successfully.
2. but after the first installation the VM will restart then it will hangs on the following black screen "VM starting . press f2 "to enter setup, f12 for network boost......"
3. I remove the VM re-install another one and the same problem is still there.

So ant one can advice on what the problem might be?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Did you check google if there are any compatibility issues?

Did you check the settings of the windows environment you installed as a guest OS?

Hows the HDD set up on the VM?

Comment: HD is set up as single imag

Comment: Did the image ever load successfully? Are you able to go safemode?